# Importing Equations from MathJax

Tags: import, latex

I have to use some complicated mathematical equations from a previous publication in my Mathematica notebook. These equations are available on science direct webpage in MathJax format, but I am not able to copy them as such. Also, I am able to select only one of them at a time.

Is it possible to copy/download these equations in some format readable by Mathematica.

Will appreciate any suggestion.
thanks

Comment: `ToExpression[..., TeXForm]`, e.g., `ToExpression["\sin x",TeXForm]`

Comment: Thanks, but how to give the address of the webpage to mathematica. These Equations are available online.

Comment: Check `Import` for downloading websites.  If the equations are just *part* of a webpage, you'll simply have to cut and paste.

Comment: I tried, but cut/copy is not an option on right clicking. Copy/pasting it from PDF anywhere gives only some funky symbols around. Import is not working as well, it imports only the title etc. to Mthematica not equations.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the equation, then choose Show Math As, then either MathML or TeX Commands.  Copy the code that is shown and paste it into Mathematica.

[image]

Mathematica can interpret both TeX and MathML, but it does not handle either perfectly.  If one doesn't give a good result, it's worth trying the other.